# Frobenius twist of a field

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, vector-spaces, commutative-algebra, positive-characteristic

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p>0$ (not necessarily perfect). Consider the Frobenius endomorphism $F : k \to k$, $x \mapsto x^p$. I am curious about what happens when we take $k$ as a $k$-vector space, and restrict scalars along $F$. We get a new $k$-vector space $F_*(k)$, and I wonder how does it look (possibly even when $k$ is perfect)? Can we give a basis for $F_*(k)$? Is it finite dimensional?

I will also be interested if we can say something more generally about $F_*(V)$ for $V$ a finite dimensional $k$ vector space. Thank you

EDIT: I am still interesting in the question. From the comments, we have the following simplification by reuns:

> Find a basis for $k$ as a $k^p$-vector space.

I did not understand the rest of reuns' suggestion for how to do it though.

Comment: My first guess is that the answer depends on the transcendence degree of $k/\Bbb                           {F}_p$. Surely somebody knows this.

Comment: would it be possible to migrate this to mathoverflow?

Comment: If $k$ is perfect, $F$ is an automorphism so extending scalars along it won't change that much.

Comment: What does it mean extend scalars along $F$, how do you define $F_*(k)$ ? Looking at the degree, basis and generating set of $k/k^p$ is first step to understand the lack of separability and perfectness.

Comment: @reuns I meant to write *restrict* scalars, sorry! So $F_*(k)$ is the same underlying ab.grp. but the $k$-vector space structure is twisted by $F$.

Comment: I still don't understand, explain clearly... $F(k) = k^p$ is a subfield, do you mean looking at $k$ as a $k^p$ vector space and finding a basis ? If so then pick a transcendental basis $x_1,\ldots,x_m$ of $k^p/\Bbb{F}_p$ let $L_n =  \Bbb{F}_p(x_1^{1/p^n},\ldots,x_m^{1/p^n})$ and look at $k/k^p/L_\infty/L_1/\Bbb{F}_p$ (for simplicity assume $m$ is finite)

Comment: @reuns If $F: k \to K$ is a field extension, then any $K$-vector space $V$ can be viewed as a $k$-vector space $F_*(V)$ via $\lambda v = F(\lambda) v$.

Comment: @Max But $F$ can be an automorphism without being identity. In particular, $F^*$ and $F_*$ aren't necessarily just the identity functors. So it's still interesting if $k$ is perfect

Comment: @reuns Yes I think what you said is what I'm asking, since we can replace $F : k \to k$ by the field extension $F(k) = k^p \to k$. Would you mind elaborating on this though? I would love a reference

Comment: If $k$ is perfect, they are isomorphic to $k$ as vector spaces, because $F$ is an automorphism. Restricting or extending scalars along an isomorphism always produces something isomorphic

Comment: @Max I don't think I agree. If $F$ is an isomorphism then $F^*F_*$ and $F_*F^*$ are (isomorphic to) identity, but I don't see why $F_*$ or $F^*$ should be.

Comment: Mhm yes I see your point I spoke too quickly.